# Largest volume of a parallelepiped when one of the vector is specified

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider three vectors $\hat{c}$, $\hat{l}$ and $\hat{m}$. Let norm of $\hat{c}$ , $c < 1$ whereas, norm of $\hat{l}$ and $\hat{m}$ are $1$. Now, my question is what would be the maximum volume of the parralelopiped constructed from the three vectors $\hat{c}$, $\hat{l}$ and $\hat{m}$?

Comment: $V\le \hat c\hat l\hat m.$  As the problem is stated, 1 is the least upper bound.

Comment: upvote for the word parallelepiped, welcome to SE

Comment: @DougM will you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: If the vector are orthogonal (at right angles to one another) then the volume will be the product of the lengths.  And if they are not, then the volume will be less than the product of their lengths.  Since the length of c is less than 1, and the length of l and m equal 1, we can say that $V < 1$  but if $V<1$ how do we express the maximum value of $V$ technically the maximum does not exist.  But we can can say it is effectively 1.  Or 1 is the smallest boundary value.

Comment: When all the vectors are orthogonal then the volume is just c which is less than $1$. Is it the maximum volume?

Comment: Yes, it is, if $c$ is fixed. Your phrasing can also be interpreted as saying that $c$ is allowed to be anything $<1$, in that case there is no maximum.